# Getting error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX platform, when I run my script code, I got the same error again and again

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Kindly help me with find the cause of the error.

```
create table roles
(
    "role_id" number(5,0) not null,
    "name" varchar2(20) not null,
    constraint "rle_pk" primary key ("role_id")
);

create table users
(
    "user_id" number(5,0) not null,
    "first_name" varchar2(15) not null,
    "last_name" varchar2(15) not null,
    "contact_number" number(15,0) not null,
    "address" varchar2(30) not null,
    "RLE_id" number(5,0) not null,
    constraint "usr_pk" primary key ("user_id")
);

alter table "users" 
      add constraint "usr_rle_fk" 
          foreign key ("RLE_id") references "roles"("role_id");
```

Comment: You have two `CREATE TABLE` statements here, followed by one `ALTER` statement.  Which statement is generating this error?

Comment: **ALTER TABLE** is generating an error.

Comment: Not that it should matter, but `ROLES` is a (non reserved) Oracle keyword.  You should avoid using it to name your tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a CREATE TABLE ... statement WITHOUT using "double quotes" for the *name* of the table, then the table's name will be stored using all UPPERCASE letters.

When you are using "double quotes", then you are enforcing case-sensitivity. That's why the ALTER TABLE statement fails (users <> USERS, roles <> ROLES).  You would have to write:

```
alter table "USERS"  
add constraint "usr_rle_fk" foreign key ("RLE_id")
references "ROLES"("role_id");
```

Better: avoid double quotes when writing DDL code eg

```
SQL> create table roles
  2  (
  3   role_id number(5,0) not null,
  4      name varchar2(20) not null,
  5      constraint rle_pk primary key (role_id)
  6  );

Table ROLES created.  -- notice: table name all upper case

SQL> 
SQL> create table users
  2  (
  3      user_id number(5,0) not null,
  4      first_name varchar2(15) not null,
  5      last_name varchar2(15) not null,
  6      contact_number number(15,0) not null,
  7      address varchar2(30) not null,
  8      RLE_id number(5,0) not null,
  9      constraint usr_pk primary key (user_id)
 10  );

Table USERS created. -- notice: table name all upper case

SQL> 
SQL> alter table users add constraint usr_rle_fk foreign key (RLE_id)
  2  references roles(role_id);

Table USERS altered.
```

When working with APEX (version 19, using SQL Workshop/SQL Commands) you only see the message "Table created" when creating a table, but not the table name as such.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider your CREATE TABLE statement ...

```
create table users
```

... with your ALTER TABLE statement:

```
alter table "users"
```

Your use of the double-quotes in the second statement is the cause of the ORA-00942. Double-quotes make the identifier **case sensitive**. Consequently `USERS` does not equal `"users"`. So remove those double-quotes and the problem will disappear.